# How to make VSCode suggest more files in import?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I want it to automatically import files it does it perfectly but other times it just does not suggest at all. I have to import each file by typing out individually. Is there any setting to improve VSCode importing suggestions or change the directories it looks in?
Many times it does not even suggest to import useContext, State, etc.

Comment: I never use `useContext` in my imports, but that might be a language difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visual Studio Code** is a great, free tool, but If you have installed too many `extensions`, they may not cooperate properly, they may cause conflicts . And this in turn causes VSCode to work **exactly** as You describe. It's ponderous and doesn't work as it should. Loose its weight, `get rid of` **unused**, **unnecessary**, conflicting extensions. And you will see that everything will be back to normal;-)